# Parse mtgapi's response into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array, explode

I would like to have the data returned from mtgapi to be placed into an array of associative keys and values.

Sample output can be found at http://mtgapi.com/docs.

As the output is returned as a string, I pull it into PHP as a string using `file_get_contents($url);`

Edit:
I did not know the return is a JSON object! Simple!

Comment: `json_decode()`? http://3v4l.org/Dl6eY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning a JSON object. You should use `json_decode`.

Try:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)